# ideal() in R package pscl not producing repeatable results

Tags: r, mcmc, pscl

I'm working with the `pscl` package in R and trying to get it to produce testable/reproducible results. I've taken a look at the underlying C code and it *appears* as though `GetRNGstate()` and `PutRNGstate()` are being called in the right places but it seems impossible to repeat output from the MCMC model.

I've packaged up the functions in `simulationResult` from the **SoDA** package so I can verify the start state of each simulation R on the R side.

```
library(pscl)
library(SoDA)
run1 <- simulationResult(
  ideal(s109, 
    normalize=TRUE,
    maxiter = 500,
    thin = 10,
    burnin = 0),
  seed = 42)

run2 <- simulationResult(
  ideal(s109, 
    normalize=TRUE,
    maxiter = 500,
    thin = 10,
    burnin = 0),
  seed = 42)
```

We can verify that the start states are the same at least on the R side:

```
all.equal(run1@firstState, run2@firstState)
```

But the output is different:

```
all.equal(run1@result$xbar, run2@result$xbar)
```

I can increase the number of iterations but that shouldn't really matter if the RNG state is getting propogated. Am I missing something really simple? Thanks.

**Edit**: I should also note that `all.equal(run1@lastState, run2@lastState)` (the end state of each run) should be the same but they end up different. My guess is that some source of contingency outside of the R RNG functions called by C is impacting the *number* of times those RNG functions are called. Curious.

**Edit2**

I should also add I'm on R 3.0.1 with pscl 1.04.4 on OS X 10.8.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suspected by OP and @SchaunW, the problem lies in the C code. "A bit" of digging revealed a quite subtle problem (see the [source](http://r-cran-pscl.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.03.5-1/files.html) code, not the newest version though):

All the sampling in ideal.c appears in the part of *commence iterations*, i.e. where functions `updatex`, `updatey` and others are used. However, the problem is with one of the arguments of these functions - the matrix `ok` (ironic, right?). It is used by `updatex` and `updateb` and **only** the positions where `ok == 1` are important ([in](http://r-cran-pscl.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.03.5-1/crossprod_8c-source.html) `crosscheck`, `crosscheckx`).

Before that, some values of `ok` are assigned to be 1 in `check(y,ok,n,m)`.

However, at the very beginning the initial values of `ok` are denoted by

```
ok = imatrix(n,m);
```

which allocates a integer matrix (see util.c for `imatrix`). The problem is that then `ok` contains various numbers, i.e. not only zeros and sometimes ones. It seems that they are not related to RNG state of R, which explains the behaviour noted by @SchaunW: `all.equal(run1@result$xbar, run2@result$xbar)` returns `TRUE` if `!any(ok == 1)` and vice versa. Also, different number of ones explains different `lastState`.

I am not an expert in C and I am not sure whether there is a logic error in the code or if the `imatrix` function should be corrected, but a straightforward fix could be to fill `ok` with zeros right after initialisation:

```
ok = imatrix(n,m);
for(a=0; a<n; a++) {
    for(aa=0; aa<m; aa++) {
      ok[a][aa] = 0;
    }
}
```

Finally, there is also a fix that does not include modifying the C code (it might not be right for your applications though). Functions `crossxyi`, `crossxyj` are used instead of `crosscheck`, `crosscheckx` (the bad ones) when `impute = TRUE` for `ideal`.

Comment: @Adam Hyland, let me know if you want any more details.

Comment: I'll take a look at this tonight. I talked to a co-worker of mine and he noted that IDEAL.c is also calling (via `dtnorm`) the R rng functions (e.g. `exp_rand`) a variable number of times (which helps explain the end RNG state being different). I'll see if this impacts those calls or if there are 2 problems. :) Thanks.

Comment: How does it come that those functions are called a variable number of times? I would guess that it should not be a problem since this fix of filling `ok` with zeros also returns constant `lastState`.

Comment: Bingo. This works, or at least it provides the correct result. I'll investigate the other issues with the package on my own time. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

I have not been able to reproduce the results I originally posted. When I got those results the first time, I closed out R, restarted it, and ran the whole thing again just to make sure, and I got the same results again. What appears below is copied exactly from my R console. However, I just tried the code a third (and fourth and fifth) time and it is not working. I'm leaving my original answer up just in case I was onto something and didn't realize it and it can be of use to someone else, but the advice below does not appear to work (at least not consistently).

The problem does seem to lie in the C code. When I open up the `ideal` function and run it line by line, `all.equal` returns TRUE for every input in this line of code:

```
output <- .C("IDEAL", PACKAGE = .package.Name, as.integer(n), 
      as.integer(m), as.integer(d), as.double(yToC), as.integer(maxiter), 
      as.integer(thin), as.integer(impute), as.integer(mda), 
      as.double(xp), as.double(xpv), as.double(bp), as.double(bpv), 
      as.double(xstart), as.double(bstart), xoutput = as.double(rep(0, 
        n * d * numrec)), boutput = as.double(0), as.integer(burnin), 
      as.integer(usefile), as.integer(store.item), as.character(file), 
      as.integer(verbose))
```

However, when I run the above code multiple times, `output$xoutput` returns slightly different results each time, even if I call `set.seed(42)` immediately before each run.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] SoDA_1.0-5       pscl_1.04.4      vcd_1.2-13       colorspace_1.2-0 gam_1.06.2       coda_0.16-1      lattice_0.20-10  mvtnorm_0.9-9994
[9] MASS_7.3-22     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.2
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The `ideal` function has a `startvals` argument. The default for that argument is "eigen". For your call to `set.seed` to have an effect, you need to change that argument to "random". Here's what you already tried:

```
run1 <- simulationResult(
   ideal(s109, 
     normalize=TRUE,
     maxiter = 500,
     thin = 10,
     burnin = 0,
     startvals = "eigen"),
   seed = 42)

run2 <- simulationResult(
   ideal(s109, 
     normalize=TRUE,
     maxiter = 500,
     thin = 10,
     burnin = 0,
     startvals = "eigen"),
   seed = 42)

all.equal(run1@firstState, run2@firstState)
[1] TRUE

all.equal(run1@result$xbar, run2@result$xbar)
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.01832379"
```

And here's the same thing with `startvals` set to "random":

```
run1 <- simulationResult(
   ideal(s109, 
     normalize=TRUE,
     maxiter = 500,
     thin = 10,
     burnin = 0,
     startvals = "random"),
   seed = 42)

run2 <- simulationResult(
   ideal(s109, 
     normalize=TRUE,
     maxiter = 500,
     thin = 10,
     burnin = 0,
     startvals = "random"),
   seed = 42)

all.equal(run1@firstState, run2@firstState)
[1] TRUE    

all.equal(run1@result$xbar, run2@result$xbar)
[1] TRUE
```

As far as I can see, the need to set `startvals` to "random" in order to get replicable results is not clearly indicated in the package documentation. I had to play around with it for a while before I figured it out.

Comment: I just tried this out and I'm still seeing a difference in the results. I'll try and provide some more information because I'm curious about this. What is your system/version/etc. ?

Comment: It consistently gave the right results earlier today, but now it's not. I have no idea what changed within the space of a few hours. See edits above.

Answer (score 1):

It's an MCMC model so it necessarily uses random number generation. To get repeatable results, you need to start your analysis by setting a 'seed' for the random number generator. This way each time you build the model, it uses the same "random" numbers (as long as you reset the seed each time you build the model. use the `set.seed()` function and just feed it an arbitrary value, like `1234`.

I'm not familiar with this package and it looks like you might already be setting a seed for random number generation in your function call with `seed=42`, but I'd recommend setting it explicitly with `set.seed()` anyway. Your code then becomes:

```
set.seed(1234)
run1 <- simulationResult(
  ideal(s109, 
    normalize=TRUE,
    maxiter = 500,
    thin = 10,
    burnin = 0),
  seed = 42)

set.seed(1234)
run2 <- simulationResult(
  ideal(s109, 
    normalize=TRUE,
    maxiter = 500,
    thin = 10,
    burnin = 0),
  seed = 42)
```

Comment: `simulationResult` should set the seed in the same way as `set.seed()`, I think. if you do your answer you'll see they still aren't equal `all.equal(run1@result$xbar, run2@result$xbar)` (either w/ the seed argument set as you did or with it removed so the seed is `1234`.

Comment: Weird. That's all I got. Try contacting the package maintainer: Simon Jackman <jackman at stanford.edu>